# ¿Cómo soluciono este problema al crear tablas relacionadas con Laravel ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, relaciones, framework

Estoy creando la siguiente migración:

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name', 128);
            $table->string('slug', 128)->unique();
            $table->mediumText('extract')->nullable();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->enum('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT'])->default('DRAFT');
            $table->string('file', 128)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            // Relaciones
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('id')->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Pero cuando corro la migración ya sea desde 0 con `php artisan migrate`  o `php artisan migrate:refresh`  me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro dar con el problema. Mi base de datos es MARIADB que está instalada con Laragon. Creó que es un problema con la manera en que está creada la base de datos, no estoy seguro. ¿Alguién ha tenido este problema alguna vez?

Comment: Esas tablas a las que referencias tienen que existir previamente. Además el tipo de dato de las columnas debe ser el mismo

Comment: Ya existen varias publicaciones al respecto en la comunidad, usa el buscador para filtrar y verás como darle solución

Comment: El orden de las tablas importa y deben crearse de manera que, la ultima reciba las FK. En tu caso seria: Usuario -> Categoria -> Post, post es la ultima y es la que tendria `user_id` y `categoria_id`.

Comment: Como se define el orden de la creación de las tablas? Si las creo con php artisan

Comment: @JuanFernandoHuenchun primero debiste crear la migración de donde tomarás la llave primaria y luego la migración donde la usas para establecer la llave foránea, eso mas el hecho de que los tipos de datos como ya te dijeron deben empatar. Por cierto hasta aqui no tendría nada que ver el ORM, solo estás creado las tablas por medio del sistema de migraciones, es todo